# Material UI CustomTextField not accepting Tooltip and password hide / show icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJEb.png)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj7vN.png)
Material UI Tooltip and password field icons are not accepting the customTextField.How to overcome this, can i have some help?

Trying to resolve the issue in customTextField